# Best Way to escaping single quotes and double quotes in a string

Tags: string, jsp

What is best way to eliminate single quotes and double quotes from an jsp variable?

Assume `text="hsdhakb'asda"'ass'as'd"`

We have two options
either using `fn:replace` or `fn:escapeXml()`

```
  <c:set var='text' value='${text}'/>
```

Comment: If I recall my html correctly, you will need to *always* be consistent with your quote options (`'` vs `"`) for any approach to work consistently.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [**fn:escapeXml()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) because It escapes quotes and also other characters that could be interpreted as XML markup. .

It also helps in prevention of XSS attack in JSP.

Comment: but it gives some issue while i use in jsp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055225/overlib-js-unable-to-display-tooltip-having-double-quotes-in-text

Comment: please give ur answer on above issue in link

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)